# メインメニューに登録したマイマクロからマクロが実行されない

Tags: emeditor

お世話になります。

公式サイトのフォーラムにも投稿しましたが、数日経っても投稿が反映されないため、こちらに改めて投稿をいたします。

ツール→メニューの変更→メインメニューで、「マイマクロ」というポップアップを作成し、
そこへ右に挿入で、マイマクロの一覧を登録しています。

ところが、いつのバージョンからか、メニューからマイマクロ→適当なマクロを選択しても、
そのマクロが実行されなくなりました。

ただ、表示されるマイマクロから適当なマクロを右クリック→編集などを選択すると、
編集モードで開きますので、どうやら選択による実行だけが動作していないようです。

このほか、キーボードの割り当てで、いくつかのマクロにショートカットキーを割り当てており、
このショートカットを押すと、マクロは実行されます。

また、コンテキストメニューにも同じようにマイマクロの一覧を登録しているのですが、
こちらからは問題なく実行されます。

気が付いたのは 21.4.1 で、21.5.1、21.5.2 に更新してみましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。
環境は、Windows 10 Home/21H1 Emeditorは64ビット版です。

なお、別の端末（Windows 10 Home/21H2 、EmEditor 21.0.1）では問題ありませんでした。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、[マクロ] メニューの [カスタマイズ] を選択し、[既定でマクロを非同期に実行する] オプションをクリアして、問題が再現するかどうか試してください。それで問題が解決するかどうかお知らせください。

**更新**
マクロに関連付けられたイベントを解除するか `EmEditor v21.5.904` 以上に更新してください。

Comment: お世話になります。

ご指摘のオプションについて、有効となっていたため、無効にしましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。
EmEditor 自体も一度終了させてみましたが、こちらも同じく変わりませんでした。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: メイン メニューをカスタマイズして、マクロを実行しているのですね。そのマクロのパスが正しくない可能性があるため、メニューのカスタマイズで、正しいマクロが選択されているか、マクロのパスを確認してみてください。

Comment: ファイルパスに間違いはありませんでした。念の為、新たに簡単なマクロを作成して保存、「これを選択」を実行してから、このマクロをマイマクロから選択してみましたが、やはり無反応でした。

Comment: 「これを選択」を実行してから、マクロ メニューの [実行] を選択 (または基本ツール バーの [マクロの実行] ボタンをクリック) では、問題なく動作しますか? どのような簡単なマクロでも問題が再現しますか? それとも特定のマクロで問題が発生しますか? 特定のマクロで問題が再現する場合には、できるだけシンプルな問題が再現するサンプル マクロを作成して、そのマクロを示してください。

Comment: マクロメニューの実行からは正常に動作しました。また、今回の問題は、特定のマクロではなく、全てのマクロで発生しています。

Comment: [マイマクロから選択] というのがどういう動作なのか、私が誤解している可能性があります。画面図をお送りください。また、[ツール] メニューの [インポートとエクスポート] を選択し、[すべての設定をレジストリ ファイルにエクスポート] を選択してエクスポートしたファイルのすべて (サブ フォルダ AppData を含む) を zip に圧縮して、私宛 (tech @ emurasoft.com) に送っていただけますか?

Comment: 先ほど、ご指示のありましたファイルをお送りしました。ご確認、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: メールありがとうございます。マクロに関連付けられたイベントを解除していただくことで、問題が解決しました。またこの問題は v21.5.904 以上で修正されています。

Comment: 補足。江村さまとのやり取りの結果、以下のことがわかり、解決しました。

・マイマクロの中に、フォーカスを取得した時に動作するイベントマクロがあった
・マイマクロを開いた瞬間に、このイベントマクロが発動していたため、実際に選択したマクロが実行されていなかった（問題のイベントマクロが、わかりやすい動きをするものではなかったため、それが起動していたことに気付かなかった）


21.5.904 で対応していただき、解決したことを確認しました。
このたびは、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 原因がわかってよかったです。よろしければこの回答の左のチェックマークをクリックしてこの回答で解決したことを表してください。